# How to post/redirect data to another api in aws gateway.I want to GET data also in the same aws api gateway

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, post, get, api-gateway

My question is:

I want to GET data from one api and after filtering the data, I want to POST the data to another API in the same api gateway.

The data is in JSON format and after receiving the data, I filter the data and forward to another api.

I can filter the data, but redirecting the result data to another api, I am struggling with.

How can I do that in aws gateway?

Comment: Where you have written all these code? Is AWS Lambda function triggered when API is called?

Comment: Thanks for responding.I am not using aws lambda.I am writing the code in Integration Response. The code is #set($inputRoot = $input.path('$')) {
 
    ## Assign output properties to input properties
    "altitude": "$inputRoot.altitude"
  "vehicle_number":"$inputRoot.vehicleregnumber"
  "longitude":"$inputRoot.longitude"
   "longitude":"$inputRoot.longitude"
   #if ($inputRoot.gpsspeed >50)
 "speed" : High
#else
"speed":Low
#end
"datetime":"$inputRoot.timestamplocal"
 }

Comment: @Chetan Ranapriya do we have to use lambda for achieving the same?

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTTP integration type selecting the POST http method.

[image]

Comment: I need to GET in the same api ,parse json and forward to another api.Can you guide me?